# Clarifying understanding of Poisson Brackets in Hamiltonian Dynamics

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics, quantum-mechanics

I'm just reading through my textbook and would like to clarify my understanding of 'Canonically related variables'. In my textbook, it says that if $Q_i$, $P_i$ are related to $q_i$, $p_i$ by a canonical transformation then: $$\{Q_j,P_k\} = \delta_{j,k}$$

I'm not exactly sure what $\delta_{j,k}$ refers to, but from what I have gathered - does this refer to the **number of degrees of freedom shared by $Q_j$ and $P_k$?**

Thanks, just wanted to verify my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's just the Kronecker delta: $\delta_{i,j}$ equals $1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise.